# How to list all class members (including inherited) tha are marked with protobuf .net ProtoMember attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, protobuf-net

Having a class type (for example D that was inherited from C, that inherited from B) how to  list all class members (including inherited) that are marked with [protobuf .net ProtoMember](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) attribute in order from top parent to bottom descendant ( B members, C members, D members)?

Comment: This is an easy one: the answer is "none". `[ProtoMember]` has an `[AttributeUsage]` declaration that limits usage to properties and fields, not methods. Thus, there are precisely zero methods marked with `[ProtoMember]` at *any* level. However, if you actually mean "members", then: reflection is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the answer would be just to check with reflection, using `GetFields()`, `GetProperties()`, and `Attribute.IsDefined`. However, in this case it may be more advisable to ask the protobuf-net model what *it* thinks exists:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using System;
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(5, typeof(Bar))]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int X { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Bar : Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Bar)];
        do {
            Console.WriteLine(metaType.Type.FullName);
            foreach(var member in metaType.GetFields())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> {0}, {1}, field {2}",
                    member.Member.Name, member.MemberType.Name,
                    member.FieldNumber);
            }
        } while ((metaType = metaType.BaseType) != null);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this is that it will work even for custom configurations (attributes are not the only mechanism for configuring protobuf-net)